# PHP closure as an optional function argument

Tags: php, closures

Would be possible to specify a default argument value when argument is a PHP closure? Like:

```
public function getCollection($filter = function($e) { return $e; })
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Am i missing something (maybe a different syntax?) or it's not possible at all? Of course i know i can do:

```
public function getCollection($filter = null)
{
    $filter = is_callable($filter) ? $filter : function($e) { return $e; };
    // Stuff
}
```

(**NOTE:** I didn't test the above code)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Default arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) can only be "scalar arguments", arrays, or NULL.

["scalar values"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) in PHP are numbers, strings, and booleans.

If you want a function to be a default argument, you're gonna need to use the 2nd way, the 1st is a syntax error.

Comment: Oh, i see. So my question is useless. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Gremo: It's not a useless question, it's a good question.  Others may be wondering the same thing :-)

Comment: Agreed.  I'm a PHP dev but still found this interesting.