# PHP, set default function parameter to result of function

Tags: php, function

In PHP you can have optional parameters for a function:

```
public static function test($var = 'default string')
```

But I want to have the default value be the returned value from another function.  For example I have a method called `generateToken()` that creates a random string of desired length.  I attempted to execute the following code...

```
public static function sha512($token,$cost = 50000,$salt = self::generateToken(16)) {
        $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';
        return crypt($token, $salt);
}
```

However this throws the following error...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/www/www.domain.com/path/to/cryptography.php on line 11
```

Line 11 is the method deceleration line.  I am aware this could be done by setting the default to something like `'NONE'` and then having an if statement call the method, but I would like to do it inside the method deceleration.  How can I do this?

Comment: See answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586695/php-closure-as-an-optional-function-argument)

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) is clear: `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`

Comment: The only work around that I see is using callbacks. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @samyismyhero Would you like to post an answer with implementation using callbacks?  Not sure how you would do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Says it right in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), this cannot be done.

So instead it must be implemented like the following...

```
public static function sha512($token,$cost = 50000,$salt = null) {
    $salt = ($salt == null) ? (self::generateToken(16)) : ($salt);
    $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';
    return crypt($token, $salt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function sha512($token,$cost = 50000,$salt) {
    $salt = self::generateToken(16);
    $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';
    return crypt($token, $salt);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's highly recommended that you include some prose that helps others understand *why* or *how* your solution solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

`public static function sha512( $token, $cost = 50000, $salt = null )`

more specifically the `$salt = null`

> But I want to have the default value be the returned value from
>   another function.

Keeping to this intent this is not possible in PHP, PHP does not support first-class functions. The only workaround that I see as I mentioned in my comment above was the use of callbacks.

From what I understand the `$salt` param is intended to use what ever salt that you might like or default to the default one in your code.

So here is a possible solution although I believe you already answered your own question:

```
public static function sha512( $token, $salt = null, $cost = 50000 ) {

    // if a custom salt is provided
    if( isset( $salt ) ) {

        // calls the callback function passed in as a param
         $salt = $salt( 16 );

        // assemble the result to your specs
        $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';

        // return final result
        return crypt( $token, $salt );
    }

    // default if no custom salt is provided
    $salt = self::generateToken( 16 );
    $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';

    // return final result
    return crypt( $token, $salt );
}
```

The passed in callback must be in the current scope to be called successfully.